# regular expression to validate number pipes

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex that can validate the following:

Validate that there are no empty values or spaces

`123|2.3|3.6`

Validate that none of the numbers are negative

`123|0.0|2.3`

Validate that each number is 9 digits or less without counting digits after the decimal point

`123|333333333.32|3.4`

Here is my attempt:

```
^(?:[^|]+(?:\|[^|]+){0,2})?$
```

Comment: Are the decimal places limited? From your first attempt it looks as they are between 0 and 2.

Comment: Yes de decimal places is limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this one:

```
^(\d{1,9}(?:\.\d+)?)\|(\d{1,9}(?:\.\d+)?)\|(\d{1,9}(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

First number:

```
(\d{1,9}(?:\.\d+)?)
```

`\d{1,9}` indicates 1 and up to 9 digits. `(?:\.\d+)?` indicates a possible decimal period and one or more digits after it.

For the subsequent numbers `\|` indicates a pipe and after that I include the same regex as for the first number `(\d{1,9}(?:\.\d+)?)`

I encapsulate each number in `()` to make each number a capturing group. In case you don't need to capture the numbers and you only need to validate, this one also works:

```
^\d{1,9}(?:\.\d+)?(?:\|\d{1,9}(?:\.\d+)?){2}$
```

Comment: How could I validate that they are always with number | number | number

Comment: This regular expression does that. Or you mean they are always three numbers?

Comment: Yes are always three Numbers for example 12|12.4|12.5 correct 12 incorrect 12|6 incorrect

Comment: Ok, and after the decimal point, how many digits can there be?

Comment: no matter how many number after the decimal

Comment: I modified my answer with these new requirements.